# Page content to the right is being pushed off screen when using responsive table in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have the following html ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hgaf74y/)):

```
<div class="d-flex" style="max-width: 1460px;">
   <div style="width: 100%; background: red;">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="background: green; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; margin-left: 1rem;">
      2
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the JSFiddle, the content is being pushed off screen to the right even though I am using the responsive table class. The layout is supposed to be main content + sidebar content, but the sidebar content is being pushed off screen for some reason. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sidebar is being pushed off the side of the viewport because of:

- The `width: 100%` on the `.table-responsive` element's `<div>` parent.
- The fact that elements have `min-width: min-content` by default in a horizontal flex layout.

Consider removing the `width: 100%` and apply `min-width: 0` to override the `min-width: min-content`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex" style="max-width: 1460px;">
   <div style="min-width: 0; background: red;">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
                  <td>Example</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="background: green; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; margin-left: 1rem;">
      2
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex doesn't like its item with `width` and would rather handle that on its own.
So I removed one div with `width: 100%` and it worked.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="d-flex" style="max-width: 1460px;">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="background: green; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; margin-left: 1rem;">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```